# MySQL Workbench unable to startup/shutdown from remote

Tags: mysql, amazon-ec2, mysql-workbench

I have a MySQL database running on Amazon EC2 and have configured MySQL Workbench to connect to it. I can get into the Workbench Admin screen, but the problem I am facing is the 'Startup/Shutdown' is disabled from Workbench. It displays the following message:

[image: Workbench Remote Administration is disabled]

The Options File screen is also disabled:

[image: Workbench options screen disabled]

Answer (score 1):

I was able to fix the issue. Basically I connected the admin GUI to mysqld using root user id. The reason seems to be the admin GUI tried to modify the /etc/my.cnf file which only root has the priviledge. Ofcourse you can create another user id with similar priviledge as root and try it

Answer (score 1):

have you set up remote access for the remote administration?
[image: WB remote admin settings]

Answer (score 0):

As a alternative use the command line. Connect a ssh terminal to the Linux box.

If you are using mysql on RedHat Linux (Fedora Core/Cent OS) then use following command:

- To start mysql server:

  ```
  /etc/init.d/mysqld start
  ```
- To stop mysql server:

  ```
  /etc/init.d/mysqld stop
  ```
- To restart mysql server

  ```
  /etc/init.d/mysqld restart
  ```

This will also test if your SSH connections are up and running. Apparently workbench needs this. This is also going to be a lot less hassle to figure out. If you need to modify the configuration of the mysql file make sure you have nano installed and just edit the mysql.cnf files with nano.

Comment: as i have stated above, i am able to login to WB and do queries, meaning i have already started the myslqd service. I did login to linux using ssh and did the following to start the mysqld service,
"sudo service mysqld start"
But my intention is to be able to not just start/stop from WB, but do complete MYSQL administration from WB